# TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function - How do I solve it?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I was trying to create an auto chatbot with bothub.

It's a very new experience for me and I am stuck here

I wish that I could find an answer here.

```
    JamesLees-MacBook-Pro:kakaotalkchatbot root# bothub logs
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/bothub", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bothub_cli/main.py", line 539, in main
cli()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 721, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1065, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 894, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bothub_cli/main.py", line 497, in logs
log_entries = lib_cli.logs()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bothub_cli/lib.py", line 291, in logs
self._load_auth()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bothub_cli/lib.py", line 298, in _load_auth
self.config.load()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bothub_cli/config.py", line 46, in load
with open(self.path, encoding='utf8') as fin:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

This is what I am getting and I cannot proceed from this

```
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this
```

I would at least like to know what is the problem

It's still okay if it's not solvable

I would love to get suggestions with chatbot too

Thanks.

Comment: The library uses Python 3 code. You should use Python 3 as well.

Comment: In python 2.7, there is no `encoding` parameter, so just `with open('path', 'r') as f`